# google d8 (v8 shell), outputs "undefined" on every press of return key

Tags: javascript, shell, installation, v8

I have google v8 version 4.6.0 running on linux mint rafaela, downloaded with gclient and built using "make native console=readline -j4".
Now whenever I have d8 shell running, it outputs undefined when I press return key.
 What's the reason for this behavior? and How do I make it stop? 
For example, here is an excerpt from terminal.

```
~/js/v8/out/native/d8
V8 version 4.6.0 (candidate)
d8> print("hello world")
hello world
undefined
d8>          //(I had pressed enter key here.)
undefined
d8> print("something")
something
undefined
d8>
```

Edit:
According to answers of @Xufox and @"Denys Séguret", undefined here is the return type from print function, and return type is also undefined in case of pressing enter key. 
But why doesn't it displays same behavior on loading the scripts from a file.
Ex. file "test.js" contains

```
function foo() {
    return "foo's return";
}
print("hello1");
print("hello2");
foo();
print("hello3");
print("hello4");
```

And on loading it in d8.

```
~/js/v8/out/native/d8
V8 version 4.6.0 (candidate)
d8> load("test.js")
hello1
hello2
hello3
hello4
undefined
d8>
```

It has only one "undefined", which i am guessing is the result of me pressing enter key after load instruction.
Moreover it doesn't shows the return value of "foo function". So I am guessing, its ignoring the return value of functions and undefined is actually the result of return key only? Am I wrong? Can I convince him to ignore the return key as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every input into D8 is evaluated as a script, and then the result of that script is printed. This result is the script's so-called *completion value*, as defined in the language specification. That is one of these crazy JavaScript things, and the details of its definition are pretty ridiculous. But roughly, it is the value of the last expression statement that was executed, or `undefined`, if no such statement was reached. It is the same notion that also defines the result value of an `eval` call.

Answer (score 0):

The second output is the result of the statement/expression you entered. In your case it's always `undefined`.

Try entering an expression returning a value, like `2+2` instead.

You get the same behavior in the console of your browser:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`undefined` is the *return value* of the function. It’s similar to `console.log(…)`: the function *logs* the content but *returns* nothing (i.e. `undefined`). You can type

```
typeof console.log(4);
```

which returns `"undefined"` (before actually logging `4`), because that’s the type of the return value. The return value and the logging to the console are two seperate processes.

Look at this picture:

[image: Return vs. Logs in the Console]

This is from the console in Firefox. The lines with a white strip are *log messages*, the ones with a grey strip and a left arrow are inputs and the ones with a right arrow are *return values*. Each browser behaves differently with this.

Some browsers don’t do anything when the input is empty, however with a whitespace or line break `undefined` gets returned as well.

You’ll see, that `console.log(…)` *returns* `undefined`, but `7` actually *returns* `7`. So simply don’t use `print(…)` but just the value within it.